# How to update custom field (Delivery_date) on sales_order table on plugins?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, table

I have already created custom field `delivery_date` on `sales_order` by `UpgradeDataInterface`. And I have implemented the plugins `aroundSave()` on module-sale by modify checkout process. I would like update the delivery date in particular order.
Is that implement by using `AbstractCollection` ?

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can use event checkout_submit_all_after for solution.

```
<event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="btn_sales_order_place_after" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Observer\OrderItem" />
    </event>
```

and in observer you can do like below:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

$deliveryDate = '28-2-2016';
$order->setData('delivery_date',$deliveryDate);
$order->save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is use observers, depending on which step of the checkout are you want to update data is the observing you should use. Please check the list of native observers magento dispatch or you can crate you own dispatch (this last thing depending of some other things)

Best,
ALe.